# How many years would it take the Pioneer space probe to travel to Proxima Centauri with its current speed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, space-travel

Pioneer space probe moving at a speed of $30km/s$.
Assuming its heading for Proxima Centauri, which is situated at $4.2ly$ from earth, calculate how long it would take to get there in years, to the nearest year?

Could you please help.

Comment: [According to Google](http://www.google.ca/#q=4.2+light+years+%2F+30+km%2Fs): 41 971 years

Answer (score 1):

1 year is approximately $y = 3.15 \times 10^7 s$, and light travels at $c = 3.00\times 10^5 km/s$, so convert the speed of the space probe in km/s into ly/s and then into ly/y.

Note that $\frac{km}{s} = \frac{km}{s} \left(\frac{3.15 \times 10^7s}{1 y}\right)   \times \left(\frac{ly}{3.00\times 10^5 km/s \times 3.15 \times 10^7s}\right) = \frac{1}{30.0\times 10^4} \frac{ly}{y}$

You should be able to take it from here...

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $30 \,km \, s^{-1}$ is about $\dfrac{1}{10000}$ times the speed of light and more precisely  $\dfrac{30000}{299792458}$ times
- Distance of $4.2$ light years
- Number of years neded is ...